# How to select third image in a page using Xpath or CSS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to select the third image on the page using XPath or CSS.

I tried using the below command:

```html
xpath=//img[@class='s-image']
```

Comment: Please, add relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ ] to reference the nth element for instance.index starts from 1 not 0.
The **[ ]** operator has higher precedence (**priority**) than the **//** abbreviation.

```
xpath=(//img[@class='s-image'])[n]
```

instead of n you can put your image value.

Always to put expressions of the type **'//Expression'** in brackets when you need to specify the Nth node of their selected node-list.

Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)
link for more information.